# VS Code Extension tests not found on Azure Pipeline

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-pipelines, vscode-extensions

I have an extension, initially created using the standard `yo code` template, and successfully uploaded to the market place. I have created a test suite, which works correctly when running locally (i.e. pressing F5), and I now wanted to add CI testing to the Github repo.

I followed the instructions on [Continuous Integration](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/continuous-integration) and created a [config file](https://github.com/chrisjsewell/vscode-moose/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml). The extension now builds successfully, however it appears that no tests are discovered.

For example, in [this build](https://dev.azure.com/chrisjsewell/vscode/_build/results?buildId=4) I intentionally introduced a failing test, but it still passes.

Is there a step I'm missing or a good way to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Issue I opened](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/65919) for the answer. Currently, the tests fail silently if you do not have the required dependencies listed.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what your solution ended up being. I also noticed that my tests are passing successfully in an Azure DevOps pipeline for my extension when they should not be. Can you re-explain? I followed the CI documentation for the VS Code Extensions as well.

Comment: I took a look at your extension to see how you implemented your solution and added a mocha run command similar to yours, but it's telling me that it can't find the module vscode.  How did you solve that in your pipeline?  I saw that you have an install dependenciestask but it doesn't look like it does any commands.

Comment: I even cloned your repo and got the same result running your tests, so I'm not sure how you got yours to work?

Comment: Hey codex, the issue has been closed now and there is some more discussion in there. In it I note that, at present, none of my tests actually use the vscode module, so this is probably why I do not have an issue finding it.

Comment: The main think I would suggest, is that you check that all of your required dependencies are listed in your package.json